# Why is the pen tool not showing lines as I draw?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I am trying to draw a line from point A to point B in the picture below, that is at the same angle as the line it is extending.

[image]

Unfortunately, after placing down anchor point A, the line doesn't appear until I also place point B. This makes it very difficult to match the angle of this new line to the line it is extending to the right of point A.

I remember the pen tool previously showing a line to the next point I would place but I must have accidentally changed a setting. Does anyone know how to bring that line back?

Edit:

At this point I would just like to be able to create a line from point A to point B (see image above) that is parallel to the line to the right of point A. Here is a picture of what I am trying to emulate:

[image]

Comment: Usual pen tool operation for me is click, move mouse, click/hold/drag to adjust curve. I don't see anything before setting my curve end point.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm using Adobe Animate and just experienced something similar. Did I accidentally enable or disable something?

Answer (score 4):

`Preferences > Selection & Anchor Display >` Tick the `Enable Rubber Band for` option.

(I hate this feature, but I understand why some prefer it).

Another possible option is whether or not `Smart Guides` are active. (View > Smart Guides). If Smart Guides are active there will be a guide preview when you hover along constrain angles.

Comment: I don't see the Rubber Band option in my preferences and my smart guide is not popping up except at each 90 degree point. I posted of the settings above. I am using Illustrator CS6

Comment: CS6 doesn't have the rubber band option in Illustrator (Photoshop CS6 does though).

Answer (score 4):

As people said, you can enable rubber band help, 
but for this kind of design, as you want to be totally sure the line you draw is the same as the line already present, I would recommend copying it, and pasting it.

Select the line with Direct Selection Tool (<kbd>A</kbd>), copy, paste, then move it, then cut it.

This way you are 100% certain your line keeps the correct angle.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling the Rubber Band option for the Pen Tool will show a preview of the path as it's being created. That option doesn't exist in CS6 though (which it looks like you're using).

It's a bit more cumbersome, but you can see a preview of the path:

Click to add a new point, but *before* releasing the mouse button, hold down the space bar; that will show you the path exactly as the rubber band would. You can also let go of the space bar, drag out some bezier handles (i.e. create a curve) then hold space again to move the point with the preview or the curved path visible.